# Trouble parsing just img src from RSS feed?

Tags: php, dom, rss

I am trying to create an RSS reader based on this example:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_rss_reader.asp

Specifically, I am attempting to modify this example so that the reader will access and display all the available comic images (and nothing else) from any given web comic RSS feed. I realize that it may be necessary to make the code at least a little site-specific, but I am trying to make it as general-purpose as possible. Currently, I have modified the initial example to produce a reader that displays all the comics of a given list of RSS feeds.. However, it also displays other unwanted text information that I am trying to get rid of. Here is my code so far, with a few feeds that are giving me trouble in particular:

index.php file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function showRSS() 
        {
          if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
          {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          } else 
          {  // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
          {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
            {
              document.getElementById("rssOutput").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          }
          xmlhttp.open("GET","logger.php",true);
          xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="showRSS()">
    <div id="rssOutput"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

(pretty sure there's nothing wrong with this file; I think the problems arise in the next one although I included this one for completeness)

logger.php:

```
<?php

//function to get all comics from an rss feed
function getComics($xml)
{
    $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmlDoc->load($xml);

    $x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');
    foreach ($x as $x)
    {
      $comic_image=$x->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
      //output the comic
      echo ($comic_image . "</p>");
      echo ("<br>");
    }

}

//create array of all RSS feed URLs
$URLs =
[
    "SMBC" => "http://www.smbc-comics.com/rss.php", 
    "garfieldMinusGarfield" => "http://garfieldminusgarfield.net/rss",
    "babyBlues" => "http://www.comicsyndicate.org/Feed/Baby%20Blues",
];

//Loop through all RSS feeds
foreach ($URLs as $xml)
{
    getComics($xml);
}

?>
```

Because this method includes extra text in between the comic images (a lot of random stuff with SMBC, just a few advertisement links for gMg, and a copyright link for baby blues), I looked at the RSS feeds and concluded that the problem is that it's the description tag that includes the image source, but also includes other stuff. Next, I tried modifying the getComics function to scan directly for the image tag, rather than first looking for the description tag. I replaced the part in between the DOMDocument creation/loading and the URL list with:

```
$images=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('img');
    print_r($images);

    foreach ($images as $image)
    {
        //echo $image->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
        echo $image->item(0)->nodeValue;
        echo ("<br>");
    }
```

but apparently getElementsByTagName doesn't pick up the image tag embedded inside the description tag, because I get no comic images outputted, and the following output from the print_r statement:

```
DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 0 ) DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 0 )
```

Finally, I tried a combination of the two methods, trying to use getElementsByTagNam('img') inside the code that parses out the description tag contents. I replaced the line:

```
$comic_image=$x->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

with:

```
$comic_image=$x->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('img');
      print_r($comic_image);
```

But this also finds nothing, producing the output:

```
DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 0 )
```

So sorry for the really long background, but I'm wondering if there is a way to parse just the img src out of a given RSS feed without the other text and links I don't want?

Help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally, description content is escaped, so the following code should work:

```
foreach ($x as $y) {
    $description = $y->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0);
    $decoded_description = htmlspecialchars_decode($description->nodeValue);
    $description_xml = new DOMDocument();
    $description_xml->loadHTML($decoded_description);
    $comic_image = $description_xml->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0)->getAttribute('src');

    //output the comic
    echo ($comic_image);
    echo ("<br>");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I generally get what you are saying, and I tried out your specific code. It works for some of the feeds, but produces a weird error for others of them. For example, for SMBC, it prints out 5 valid image URLs, but then repeatedly gives me the following error: Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 30 in C:\xampp\htdocs\comic_database_logger\logger.php on line 30, which I'm very confused by. I don't understand why it expects a semi-colon in some of the description text

Comment: for baby blues, it works completely (although it puts out the URL of the image instead of the image itself, which I figure I can solve later),, and for Garfield minus Garfield, all it gives is the error listed above. Very confused

Comment: Actually, I tried just adding an @ in front of the line causing a problem because they were just warnings, and now everything works perfectly except that I need to figure out how to display the image instead of the image source link

Answer (score 0):

For the reference of anyone else reading this forum later, here is the code I ended up with. I replaced everything inside the for each loop with just a getImageSrc function that calls a getImageTag function:

```
//function to find an image tag within a specific section if there is one
function getImageTag ($item,$tagName)
{
    //pull desired section from given item
    $section = $item->getElementsByTagName($tagName)->item(0);
    //reparse description as if it were a string, because for some reason  PHP woon't let you directly go to the source image with getElementsByTagName
    $decoded_section = htmlspecialchars_decode($section->nodeValue);
    $section_xml = new DOMDocument();
    @$section_xml->loadHTML($decoded_section); //the @ is to suppress a bunch of warnings about characters this parser doesn't like
    //pull image tag from section if there
    $image_tag = $section_xml->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0);
    return $image_tag;
}

//function to get the image source URL from a given item
function getImageSrc ($item)
{
    $image_tag = getImageTag($item,'description');
    if (is_null($image_tag)) //if there was nothing with the tag name of  image in the description section
    {
        //check in content:encoded section, because that's the next most likely place
        $image_tag = getImageTag($item,'encoded');
        if (is_null($image_tag)) //if there was nothing with the tag name of image in the encoded content section
        {
            //if the program gets here,  it's probably because the feed is crap and doesn't include images,
            //or it's because this particular item doesn't have a comic image in it
            $image_src = '';
            //THIS EXCEPTION  WILL PROBABLY NEED TO BE HANDLED LATER TO AVOID POTENTIAL ERRORS
        } else
        {
            $image_src = $image_tag->getAttribute('src');
        }
    } else
    {
        $image_src = $image_tag->getAttribute('src');
    }
    return $image_src;
}
```